# iPad SplitView TableViewController width

Tags: uitableview, ipad, width

How do you change the width of the UITableViewController in an iPad SDK 3.2. It seems that it is fixed just like the iPhone UITableView.

Comment: the 3.2 beta is currently covered in an NDA

Comment: how do you change the width of the tableview in general with the iphone sdk in general.

Comment: Does anyone have a response to this question - I am also interested in an answer now that the NDA no longer applies to 3.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got your requirement what do you want to do in you application. Here you can carry out it in different way.

Instead of using UITableViewController, please use UIViewController and then add UITableView inside the UIViewController. Here you can change the frame size of UIView as you want. But you can't change the frame size of UIViewController as it is the base view and it will be the  same as iPad screen. Please do like this and let me know if you have any questions or doubts.